# My Folium does not output anything, just a blank image

Tags: python, web-scraping

In the first image, I have a map when I enter a certain range of numbers. As you can see on the second map, it maps out blank. I tried out different range and some of them crashes and outputs a blank map. For example, 300th address does not work even if I put the range from 299 to 301 and 450 does not work either. There are certain addresses block me from mapping it out. I already set the data limit to max through terminal as well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can replicate the error you're having and suggest a way to resolve it. Also, please do not post images of code as they can't be searched, cannot be copied, and are harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Mihai. I will make sure I consider them when asking questions next time. I've got the problem solved out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my own question. As for the popup, I added parse_html=True on popup which fixed my problem. Also I have just put the popup and icon function separately for clarity

```
map2 = folium.Map(location=[43.7, -79.4], tiles='cartodbpositron', 
zoom_start=11) # set default location on the map

marker_cluster = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(map2) # add the 
location to the marker cluster

for point in range(len(locationlist)): # loop through the plots

    # include popup
    popup1 = folium.Popup(df['Condo Address'][point], parse_html=True)

    # include icon
    icon1 = folium.Icon(color=df['color'][point])

    # mark every addresses in the map from the data
folium.Marker(locationlist[point],popup=popup1,icon = 
icon1).add_to(marker_cluster)
```